# HP 450 G3: Sound issue (15.10 worked fine / upgrade on 16.04 no sound)

Tags: sound, 16.04, alsa, hp

I have a new HP 450 G3

I installed Ubuntu 15.10; No sound.

Then I changed `intel.conf`: sound worked fine until 3 days ago.

New files were recommended by Ubuntu: I agreed, files were installed, since then, no sound.

Then I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04: no sound

I checked for `intel.conf` => was changed by upgrade changed intel.conf manually as under 15.10 (when sound worked aftrerwards): => still no sound terminal commands used afterwards:

```
sudo cat /proc/asound/cards: => no file or directory found
sudo lspci | grep -i audio: => no output
aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav => ...: WAVE '/usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Center.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate: 48000 Hz, mono
```

Sound seems to work... but no output...

Comment: None of these commands need super-user privileges (i. e. `sudo`) to function correctly. Are you sure that the 2nd returned no results? Did you change any BIOS settings that may have disabled the audio chipset? Can you please run `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` and `aplay -L` and [edit] your question to include the output? In the odd case that you have a USB audio device, include the output of `lsusb` instead of `lspci`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply.

Your suggestion is correct regarding bios settings. I had a bad bios Version 01.10 (which was offered temporarily by HP and removed) and upgraded it to 01.11.

Afterwards audio worked fine again and "cat /proc/asound/cards" deliveres a correct output again.

Thank you very much.
Robin